# Why does a primary key on a table prevent a query from working in VS2012?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, constraints, primary-key

Like the title says... I had a query for a sql data source in my asp/vb.net app in Visual Studio 2012.  It worked great, until I had to join a new table.  Here is the new query...

```
DECLARE @NoteAccountNumber as varchar(15)
DECLARE @NoteShortName as varchar(15)
SET @NoteShortName = '%'
SET @NoteAccountNumber = '%'
SELECT LI.NoteAccountNumber as "Account Number", 
LI.NoteFedCallCode as "Fed Call Code", 
LI.NoteShortName as "Customer Name", 
LI.NoteTypeCode as "Type Code", 
LI.RegZLoanID  
FROM MVZLoanInfo LI
JOIN MVZLoanRelationships LR on LI.NoteAccountNumber = LR.NoteAccountNumber
WHERE LI.NoteAccountNumber LIKE '%' + @NoteAccountNumber + '%' 
AND UPPER(LI.NoteShortName) LIKE UPPER('%' + @NoteShortName + '%')
```

here is the asp, for those who asked...
    
    
    
    
    '>
    
    
    '>

Now, obviously the first 4 lines of the SQL I did only in mgmt. studio, to test the query.  It ran fine there, but when I went to test the query (from the select down) in visual studio's sds wizard, it failed until I removed the primary key from the first table.

My question is, why, if the query runs fine in sql management studio, would it have issues from VS?

Comment: In what manner did it fail? Any error message? If so what was that?

Comment: We need to see your .NET code.  I suspect that you're concatenating strings and something isn't right.

Comment: Which field is the primary key?  Also the code would be helpful.

Comment: well, the asp code is the following...

Comment: I tried several times to enter the asp; too long for comments, and won't show up in an edit :/  but it's a simple gridview, 2 bound fields and 2 template fields.  The problem was happening in the sql datasource wizard though... so it wasn't in the code itself, just in the sql I was entering (above) and was erroring, saying it was violating constraints to try and join two tables on a field both shared, but was only the primary key on one of the 2 tables...

Comment: More details regarding the error are needed to resolve this if you haven't figured it out yet. The actual error message, code, or the sequence of user tasks which produced the problem.

Comment: NoteAccountNumber was the primary key on the first table, and is also on the second table, which didn't have a primary key.  The error message happened when I clicked "test query" within the VS sqldataconnection wizard (at the end) and the error said "An error occurred: One or more fields violates constraints..." (I can't copy and paste it because after removing the primary key value on that field, the error was resolved, and it's since gone live, so I don't want to redo the erroneous situation just to copy and paste what was a pretty basic error message...)